# Local notifications vs. APNS: can I have a timer periodically fetch notifications and schedule them locally to avoid using APNS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, swiftui

I am new to iOS development and am building an app with SwiftUI. In the background, I periodically pull down state from the server and the displays update accordingly.

I'd like to add notifications to my app, so when an important state change happens, the user gets a popup on their lock screen. It seems like the simplest approach would be to make an endpoint in my backend that returns notifications for a given user, periodically pull that data in the background of the app, and schedule notifications locally as necessary. This it seems would avoid the need to use APNS, but effectively accomplish the same thing.

Which makes me a little suspicious that this solution actually works. Would this solution work even if my app were running in the background? Are there any downsides to doing it this way versus using APNS that I might not be seeing?

TIA!

Comment: Yes you’re allowed to send local notifications during background refresh. But the disadvantage would be that you can’t guarantee when or if your app will run in the background. Background refresh usually goes hand in hand with sending silent remote notifications to the device signalling there is new content, so you have at least some control over getting the app to update itself. Without using APNS you won’t be able to do this. You have backend which you control, so why not just use remote notifications? Services like Onesignal or Firebase makes implementing it trivial.

Comment: @PeteMorris I suppose I was trying to retain control over how and when notifications are handled, and avoid bringing those kind of third-party services into the critical path, but I might not have a choice. It sounds like background refresh is unlikely to happen with the regularity I'd need to use my own server and local notifications in the way I'm describing? Is there any way to control when background refreshes happen (or when my async jobs will run more precisely)? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can set a minimum refresh internal, but it's advisory not guaranteed (there's no guarantee of triggering a refresh via silent remote notification either). The frequency depends on user behaviour and other on device factors. You'll have to implement background fetch either way, so you could try it with local notifications first. Firebase is tried, true, and had been well maintained and supported by Google for years. You wouldn't be letting yourself down by adding it as a dependency on the backend, in my opinion. Ship your app. If it's successful, that dependancy can always be removed later.

Comment: @PeteMorris thank you so much for that perspective, makes me feel a lot better. I actually am on GCP so I'll take a look at Firebase and see how that works. Thanks again for your help!